# can not install glibc-devel 'Requires: libnss_files.so.2' error

Tags: linux, rpm, glibc

I'm using Linux 6.1
I need to install glibc-devel but it fails with this error.

```
[root@server1 Packages]# yum install glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Examining glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
Marking glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-devel.i686 0:2.12-1.25.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libBrokenLocale.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libanl.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcidn.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypt.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnsl.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss_compat.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss_dns.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss_files.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss_hesiod.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss_nis.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss_nisplus.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: librt.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libthread_db.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libutil.so.1 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnss_files.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libutil.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnss_dns.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnss_compat.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libanl.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: librt.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libthread_db.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libm.so.6
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnss_nis.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnsl.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnss_nisplus.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libnss_hesiod.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libcrypt.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libresolv.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libdl.so.2
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libcidn.so.1
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686)
           Requires: libBrokenLocale.so.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Does this machine have Internet access?

Comment: What repos did you configure ?  Do you mean centos 6.1?

Answer (score 1):

I resovled this issue by installing glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm first.

But when installing 'glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm' I got this error. 
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686) 
           Requires: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) 
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 (/glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686) 
           Requires: libfreebl3.so

I resolved this 'libfreebl3.so' error by installing nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm  glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm at the same time. <= this is the point of the solution !!!

$ yum install nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm  glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm

After this I could install 'glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm' successfully. 
$ yum install glibc-devel-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm

Comment: installing them together worked!